# Validating Sharepoint Column doesnt contain word Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, list, validation

I want to create a single line of text column that validates following items:

Unique:can be done using OOB column settings

10 character: can be done OOB column settings

All Lower Case: How do I do this?

Can't contain word SharePoint: How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The lowcase version of field value must be the same as original value. Add the column validation formula:

```
=EXACT([YourColumn], LOWER([YourColumn]))
```

Comment: I know its an old post, but thanks for this.  I had LOWER([col]) and it refused to save...was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The below validation formula will check if field contains SharePoint or not

```
=ISERROR(FIND("SharePoint",ColumnName))
```

If it contains SharePoint then the validation fails.

```
=AND(ISERROR(FIND("SharePoint",ColumnName)),EXACT([YourColumn], LOWER([YourColumn])))
```

Comment: can we integrate both validation formula together one for lower case mentioned above by Ruslan and String validation as you provided.

Comment: @allegrooctopus yes you can use `AND`. Check my updated answer